# unable to hit my nodejs api while deploying project on heroku server

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have made a simple project where I am maintaining data of my AWS dynamoDB, on first stage I am fetching all data through db and listing items, It works perfectly when I run project on my local machine but when I deployed this on heroku it crash on hitting my node api shows 404 error here is full error screenshot

[image]

I have also test project to run project on static port but won't work.
You can check project https://funcardmaker.herokuapp.com/update

here is my Nodejs code https://gist.github.com/amit0shakya/41a91df6cccb45665fd16b869801922e

**This is heroku server log**.
2019-07-30T07:59:17.593103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/getalldata" host=funcardmaker.herokuapp.com request_id=97923dda-2645-48fd-a0c5-8cf8e69b2955 fwd="139.167.184.88" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=416 protocol=https

Comment: How do you config ```PORT``` of your ```NodeJS``` server?

Comment: @TienDuong, just in simple way const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

Comment: I think you need to share code of your ```nodejs``` server's entry file

Comment: @TienDuong I have already shared, do you need full server js code?? here is my Nodejs code https://gist.github.com/amit0shakya/41a91df6cccb45665fd16b869801922e

Comment: Yeah i need your full server js code

Comment: @TienDuong ok check it out https://github.com/amit0shakya/cardmaker

Comment: How do you deploy your project to heroku?

Comment: @TienDuong, I deploy project just using git,   1) git add . 2) git commit -am "update" 3) git push heroku master that's all my other code are working check this out: https://amitapitest.herokuapp.com/ it's console...

Comment: @TienDuong do you found anything missing in server.js in my git code???

Comment: The problem is that, you are deploying your react app to heroku instead of deploying your ```express``` app which serve your production react app to heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't use `getalldata` api because you are deploying your react app instead of deploying your `express` server which serve your production react app. So you need to config your `package.json` to start `express` server to `serve` your production react app. You just need to change `start` script in `package.json` to start `express` instead of `react`.

```
{
  "name": "cardmaker3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.464.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start-react": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "node bin/config"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this should be correct answer for this issue just because if I am not running express then why it is running on local system and fetching data from aws and  my express server is communicating with dynamoDB and if you asking for changes in package.json then you can check my other sample which is exactly same and running on heroku https://amitapitest.herokuapp.com/, github code : https://github.com/amit0shakya/apitestcode.git , this is very similar but it's working, I feel this should be routing issue on serverside, but not very sure

Comment: Please look at https://github.com/amit0shakya/apitestcode/blob/master/package.json. As you can see, your ```start``` script is starting ```express``` server
```"start": "node server",```

Comment: You should know what happen on heroku and how heroku run your app. When you push your code to heroku. It run these commandd
```npm install```
```npm run build```
```npm start```.

Comment: Why your app can run on local because on local you use this command ```npm run dev``` instead of ```npm start```

Comment: thanks, I forgot that heroku always run npm start command that's why my custom script was not running on server and I was not getting result as I was expected